# Expectations operator doubt

Tags: probability, expected-value

The question is mathematical with underpinnings of economics so I will try to explain so that the question can be understood without any knowledge of economics.

I need to maximize dividends in two periods with respect to investment (I):

max D<sub>2</sub>

D<sub>2</sub> = *f(I)* + (1-a)I

The caveat is that "**a**" is a random variable which takes on values 1 with probability p and 0 with probability (1-p)

I substitute in the value of D<sub>2</sub> and differentiate with respect to Investment.

I wrote D<sub>2</sub> = p*(f(I))* + (1-p){*f(I))* + (1-a)I}

as a is 1 if probability is p so it drops out in the first part

When I differentiate with respect to I, I get the answer as: (*f'(I*)) + 1 - p

Is this correct? The reason I ask is economically it doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 1):

When you set the derivative to zero, you are finding a stationary point, not necessarily a maximum. Is $f(I)$ a concave function? If not you might be hitting a saddle point or a minimum

Also, when you plug-in the outcomes of the random variable, it shouldn’t appear in the expectation expression. You should have $\mathbb{E}[D_2] = pf(I) + (1-p)(f(I) + I)$